# Question about notepad++ double click behavior between certain characters

Tags: notepad++

I have a question about the double click behavior. Specifically, I have noticed that certain symbols will stop the double click selection. For example, take this string of text:

```
wordsandtext-notepad-morestuff
```

If I were to double click the word 'notepad' in the following string of text, the selection of text would stop at both of the dash '-' characters. Both before and after the word 'notepad'.

Is there anyway to modify which characters notepad++ respects as stopping points for a double click selection?

If at all possible, I would like to remove all such respect for any characters, so that I can select an entire line of text with a double click.

I exhaustively looked through all of the available options within notepad++, but could not find anything that looked relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Go to “Settings > Preferences > Delimiter”

Add all characters you want in the box “Add your character as part of word”. In the screenshot below I've added hyphen and comma. When I double click on word `notepad` the whole string is selected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Toto for responding. I was hoping to ask one final question about this. When I use the triple click method to select an entire line of text, the cursor always goes immediately to the far left of the next line below it. So when I copy a line in this manner, upon pasting it, I always end up getting an extra blank line below whatever I am pasting. Is there anyway to stop notepad++ from always pasting in a blank line below whatever information I copied from a triple click on the line above?

Comment: @CleansingRitual: Unfortunatly, I don't think it's possible. AFAIK, triple clic selects the linebreak and ther're no ways to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select an entire line of text by a single click. To do this in a more easy way go to **Settings > Preferences > Editing** and check "Display line number".

This makes it easier to move the mouse and perform a single click to mark a line by clicking the line number in front of the line.

You have the same result with a triple click (but two clicks more).

In some cases a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is helpful to duplicate the current line (cursor position doesn't matter).

A workaround like press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> can be another solution combined in your copy and paste workflow.

Comment: I'm grateful for your response, help-info.de. Thanks. I wanted to ask one last final question. When I use the triple click method to select an entire line of text, the cursor always goes immediately to the far left of the next line below it. So when I copy a line in this manner, upon pasting it, I always end up getting an extra blank line below whatever I am pasting. Is there anyway to stop notepad++ from always pasting in a blank line below whatever information I copied from a triple click on the line above?

Comment: @CleansingRitual see my edit and please note, you are tending to an off-topic question here. Please remember this all must work for block copy and word wrap option too and depends on the individual use.